# Moving folder of files from CentOS server to Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, centos, filesystems, files

I have a production server and a development server.

Problem is the development server only has 20GB diskspace and about 8GB available.

The folder of files I'm trying to move is 6GB(ish).  I've tried to zip the folder and download it to the development server, except while extracting the disk space becomes full.

Is there any solution to move the folder without zipping to have it fit on the development server perfectly?

I know this can be done via FTP as I've done it from my computer, except I have only have command line access to both servers.

Any solutions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SCP to copy the files.

Example to copy the directory "foo" from the local host to a remote host's directory "bar"

```
scp -r foo your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory/bar
```

Ref: http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Comment: which server do i run the command from?  I want files on dev server, they're on the production server.  I have a folder in dev /var/www/public/dev and I want the folder on production (/var/www/html/live) to go into the folder on dev.

Comment: I would recommend to check the SCP help as it is very simple although you may need to pay attention to trailing "/" to get the correct structure. The SCP command works either way, as it is like "scp source target" command. Give it a couple of tests with small folders and see which way (copying *from* or *to* ) is more comfortable for you.

Answer (score 1):

SCP will work, but in most cases [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) is superior.

It will happily use SSH for transport just as well.